# Is there an R function to optimize the PRG AUC (area under the precision-recall-gain curve)?

Tags: r, r-caret, precision-recall

To optimize the PR AUC (area under the precision-recall curve) in Caret, the [prSummary](https://topepo.github.io/caret/measuring-performance.html#measures-for-class-probabilities) function can be plugged into the [trainControl](https://topepo.github.io/caret/model-training-and-tuning.html#the-traincontrol-function) function.

Is there a similar way to optimize the PRG AUC (area under the precision-recall-gain curve), as introduced by [Flach and Kull](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/5867-precision-recall-gain-curves-pr-analysis-done-right.pdf)? Inside or outside of Caret?

The [MLeval](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MLeval/vignettes/introduction.pdf) package returns PRG curves and PRG AUCs, but only seems to run on the Caret train output.

Comment: I trust these two answers can prove handy if you want to write your own summary: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47240996/user-defined-summaryfunction-in-caret-logloss/47241523#47241523, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52691761/additional-metrics-in-caret-ppv-sensitivity-specificity/52697940#52697940

Comment: If you still cant get around making the custom summary when you have read the linked posts, comment here and i will answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that Meelis Kull wrote an [R package for the PRG AUC](https://github.com/meeliskull/prg/tree/master/R_package). Computing the PRG AUC is as simple as:

```
prg_curve <- create_prg_curve(labels, scores)
prg_auc <- calc_auprg(prg_curve)
```

For Caret, those functions can be plugged into a summary function, as explained by @missuse in the links in the comment above.